# Can you nest anonymous functions in default values for MATLAB classes?

Tags: matlab, properties, anonymous-function, nested-function

In MATLAB, it seems like you can nest anonymous functions like this:

```
>> x = @() @() 1
x =
  function_handle with value:
    @()@()1
```

I run into problems, however, when doing this in default values for class properties. For example, if I define a class

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        Property1 = @() @() 1
    end
end
```

and construct an instance, I get an error.

```
>> MyClass
Invalid default value for property 'Property1' in class 'MyClass':
Error: Invalid use of operator.
```

What's up with this? Is there a way to do this properly?

(MATLAB R2019b)

**Edit:** Here is an interesting workaround that does not raise errors:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        Property1 = someLocalFcn
    end
end

function out = someLocalFcn
    out = @() @() 1;
end
```

Comment: Does `Property1 = {@() @() 1}` solve the problem?

Comment: @rahnema1, no, unfortunately not.

Comment: This is interesting, as in something I haven't seen before and don't at all understand. Could you explain what the purpose would be for an anonymous function that returns an anonymous function? Understand the use case might give ideas on a workaround.

Comment: Hi @CrisLuengo, yeah, this is maybe slightly esoteric. But I think it is useful. I have a superclass that needs to compute various things given by a subclass; a nice way to handle this would be to give the computation as a default property value in the subclass that the superclass can then access, but I have some computations involving function handles. I have found an (inelegant) workaround that I'll add to the question.

Comment: Yes, sorry, you're right—I've fixed it. This works for me as expeceted, without errors.

Comment: You would obtain the exact same behaviour setting `Property1 = @someLocalFcn`, and having `someLocalFcn` contain `out = @() 1;`. In that way you no longer have nested anonymous functions, I think it'd be slightly easier to read the code. Nonetheless, glad you found a workaround!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider upgrading to MATLAB 2020a, your code works as expected:

```
>> x=MyClass

x = 

  MyClass with properties:

    Property1: @()@()1

>> y=x.Property1

y =

  function_handle with value:

    @()@()1

>> z=y()

z =

  function_handle with value:

    @()1

>> z()

ans =

     1
```

Comment: Thanks @Daniel, good to know. Unfortunately my code needs to be compatible with past releases, but it seems like this may have been a bug that is now fixed. 